# Run a websocket server with Next.js (hocuspocus server)

Tags: node.js, next.js, websocket, tiptap

I am trying to build a Next.js application with collaborative editing.

To do this, I want to use The [TipTap/HocusPocus](https://github.com/ueberdosis/hocuspocus).
I have no problem running the Tiptap in Next.js, but in order to run the Hocuspus server (which is basically a websocket server), I need to run a a Node.js server.

I cannot run this as a part of the Next.js project itself, since it is serverless.

From the docs, I can see that this should be the only code required to run the Hocuspocus server.

```
import { Hocuspocus } from "@hocuspocus/server";

// Configure the server …
const server = new Hocuspocus({
  port: 1234,
});

// … and run it!
server.listen();
```

It runs fine locally, but I cannot make it run in my digital ocean enviornment since the reasons deescribed above.

I see these possible solutions:

- Running it in the Next.js project somehow
- Running it as a seperate project, but then it needs to have a static IP - right?

For both possible solutions, I am stuck on how to actually make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to why it's not working for you as I'm not sure how you've implemented it, but for anyone else who comes here, I've looked at a few options in regards to websockets, Tiptap and Next.js, and the two solutions I found that worked were:

1. Run the websocket server with Next.js custom servers: [https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server][1]
2. Create a separate websocket server

I went with option two as my hosting provider for Next.js was Vercel who doesn't provide the ability to have websockets, unless you are using one of their advertised websocket services which runs on a separate server anyway.